# Como forçar digitar um número maior que outro

Tags: javascript

##### Como forçar o usuário a digitar um número a partir de outro?

Por exemplo, o usuário ao digitar um número em um `input` o mesmo não pode ser menor que **4**, ele deve ser obrigado a digitar do número **4** em diante..

```html
<input type="number" value="deverá ser maior ou igual que 4" />
```

<sup>Sou iniciante em **JavaScript** só consigo fazer algo se tiver o código funcionando..</sup>

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Ah comunidade, não teve nada fora do critério ai vai, só queria saber sobre uma dúvida ao qual eu não consegui nem começar por não ter nem ideia da lógica para isso, mas que alguém ai na comunidade com certeza tenha.

Comment: A pergunta foi fechada porque não possui um critério definido. Não dá para saber se você quer que o usuário entre apenas com dígitos maiores que quatro ou com valores maiores que quatro. Por exemplo `22` é maior que quatro mas não é composto por dígitos maiores que quatro.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Você pode definir isso diretamente nos atributos do `input`, com `min=" "` e caso queira um numero máximo pode utilizar o `max=" "`.

Ficaria assim, por exemplo:

```
<form action="#">
  <input type="number" name="teste" min="4" max="20">
  <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Caso você realmente queira fazer com Javascript, pode fazer uma função que faz a validação se o número é maior que o especificado. A função é chamada com `onblur` quando você sai do campo input. Definindo o botão enviar inicialmente como `disabled`, e após a validação caso o número for maior, ele habilita o botão de enviar. Caso contrário não habilita o botão e retorna uma mensagem.

Segue exemplo:

```
<form action="#">
  <input type="number" id="input" onblur="checaNumero()">
  <button type="submit" id="botao-enviar" disabled > Enviar </button>
</form>
<script>
function checaNumero(){
            var botao = document.getElementById("botao-enviar");
            var input = document.getElementById("input");
            var numeroMinimo = 4;

            if (input.value > numeroMinimo) {
                //aqui habilitamos o botão
                botao.disabled=false; 

            } else{

                alert("Número precisa ser maior que " + numeroMinimo);
            }
        }

</script>
```

Comment: Olá Gabriel, não seria bem um minlength="4" o que eu não estou conseguindo, não é declarar a quantidade de caracteres digitados, mas sim digitar números maiores do que o 4, tipo, forçar o usuário a digitar número acima de 4, tipo: 4,5,6,7,8, etc... Número abaixo de 4, tipo: 3,2,1 e 0 não precisaria nem emitir um alerta, era só não permitir mesmo que fossem digitados.

Comment: Eu tentei algo como isso aqui
`var valor = document.getElementById("valor");
function validatePassword(){
ivalor.setCustomValidity("Valor precisa ser maior do que 4");
} else {
valor.setCustomValidity('');
}
}`

Comment: Você poderia criar uma validação que é chamada com `keydown`, e fizesse essa validação e caso ser menor que 4 o numero pressionado, a função apaga o numero que acabou de ser escrito imediatamente. Poderia usar essa lógica, e seria quase no mesmo sentido do que fiz mas ao invés de liberar uma mensagem, poderia apagar o numero.   Porém seria muito confuso e ineficiente e te digo o porquê, por exemplo, se o usuário fosse digitar 33, seria impedido, pois possui o numero 3 inicial ? Podes usar essa lógica e criar algo que atenda seus requisitos. Mas acredito que a melhor solução ainda, seria "MIN".

Comment: Gabriel, não daria para fazer keydown, isso impediria o usuário de digitar qualquer outro, por exemplo é o 30, sele for digitar o 30 não iria...? Eu não entendo, javascript me parece ser bem abrangente, mas não encontro nada sobre não permitir digitar um valor menor do quê 4.

Comment: Sim, como eu havia dito. Isso não daria muito certo por esse problema. Mas o que mais seria importante nesse momento é encontrar uma lógica para contornar isso, pois os recursos giram entorno destes citados.

Comment: Obg Gabriel, fiz um teste aqui com aquele exemplo que vc postou e acredito que conseguirei fazer uma alteração nele que pensei aqui.